# Blender 2.8 how to keybind pop-up menu

Tags: interface, customization, shortcut

In Blender 2.8 when you click for example `z` it brings up a pop-up menu.

There are different options to choose from and these have keybinds assosiated with them, from 1-9.

I took a look through the keybinding settings but didn't manage to find a way to edit these default keybinds, anyone know how to change them?

Comment: for me, your question is rather unclear. In 2.79 AND 2.80 i get a pie menu when hitting "z" in the 3D viewport. It is named differently (from "Shade" to "Shading") and there are different options now, as the whole viewport shading changed in itself. But its still the same?
To change keyboard shortcuts, go to "Edit" in yout top toolbar and then to "Preferences". In the new window, change to the "Input" tab. There you can change every possible Blender command to your liking.

Comment: For reference, those types of pop-up menus are referred to as 'pie-menus'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as far as I am aware the only way to change those bindings is by modifying some python files. those number are being assigned to the menu automatically in base of the order the calls are made. it kind of doesn't make too much sense but there is a specific order in which are assign. the first 4 calls will always be the S,W,E,N points and so on.

so in order have your favorite menus calls with the keybindings you like, you need to change the order of the lines.

[image]

added some duplicate lines that creates number 7 and 9

[image]

If there is another way I am not aware.. you better of learning how to do your pie menu and use that IMO.

the file in question of the `Z pie menu` in Blender 2.80 is `space_view3d.py`. you can find it in blender configuration inside the script/startup/bl_ui folder.
mac path will be

```
Application/Blender_2.80/blender.app/Contents/Resources/2.80/scripts/startup/bl_ui/space_view3d.py
```

I am not on windows right now but that will be something like

```
C:\\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.79\scripts\startup\bl_ui\space_view3d.py
```

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend that you buy the "Edit Pie Menus" add-on. It's $16 and allows you to configure ANY menu, and create any menu, including pies, in a very intuitive way from within the blender interface or within the add-on's own interface. No more scripting needed.
You can also do all kinds of cool stuff to personalise your menus, including colour coding/icon buttons which is a neat psychological trick to trigger memories more effectively.
It's regarded by many as the most handy of all add-ons and I can see why.